# identical request detected as automated

Tags: python, web-scraping, python-requests-html

How can a server detect a bot from a single HTML request identical to one made from an interactive session? For example, I can open a new private browser in Firefox, enter a URL and have everything come back 200. However, when I copy the initial HTML request that loaded the page -- url, headers and all -- and make it using a scripted tool like `requests_html` on the same device, I get a 403. What other information is the server using to differentiate between these two requests? Is there something that Firefox or `requests_html` are doing that is not visible from the developer tools and python code?

Sample code (domain substituted):

```py
from request_html import HTMLSession

url = 'https://www.example.com'
headers = {
    'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8',
    'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
    'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.5',
    'Connection': 'keep-alive',
    'DNT': '1',
    'Host': 'www.example.com',
    'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests': '1',
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_12_6) AppleWebKit/603.3.8 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/10.1.2 Safari/603.3.8'
}
session = HTMLSession()
response = session.get(url, headers=headers)
```

Comment: My guess is the page requires your browser to process some javascript code to validate it is real, which your request likely fails to do.  Try using selenium

Comment: @Chris Perform JavaScript prior to receiving the first HTML response? How does that work? How does it know what to do if this is the first request ever made to the site?

Comment: if you aren't getting any response, it might be your header, if you are getting a response you didn't expect it could be bot detection via javascript

Comment: Just to be sure. your browser and your script issue requests from the same IP address?
Just asking as if they weren't it could be that your IP adress used by request_http  got banned during your trials.

Answer (score 1):

I would really recommend using the selenium package. requests is really bad at dealing with dynamic loading and async displays. It's great for interacting with APIs, but if you're working with scraping, selenium is the tool.

Comment: Please note, that `requests_http` is written by the same author than `requests`, but is an entirely different beast. It uses a headless browser to perform and render the requests.

I still think you are right and it might be very interesting to find out whether the issue also occurs with selenium, but `requests_http` isn't as bad for scraping as you think. It also executes js code.
However for the given question it seems to be the very first requests that returns either with a 200 or with a 403 before any other request was even performed or before any java script could have been executed

Answer (score 0):

`requests_http` is using a headless Chrome/Chromium browser, so if you really send an identical request it should not be distinguishable.

Normally an http requests, contains only the the http protocol, the method, the headers

So if both are identical it is strange, that a difference can be found out by the web server.

Servers might detect timing, but I assume, that this is the very first request and that you try out both from the same IP address.

Servers might detect a request if it is 100% identical to a previously performed request, but I assume you tested this already by firs trying with your script and then with your anonymous browser.

I assume also you looked at your browser and there were no redirects involved.

Some other differences, that could occur might be during the SSL negotiation (order of keys being offered / accepted.

It might be, that your browser also tries to access 'favicon.ico' and only then the page and that `requests_http` isn't doing this.

My suggestion is to first ensure, that you are capable of reproducing a request from your browser with `requests_http`.

I'd suggest following. try to setup your own web server on your local machine, in a virtual machine, in a container on one of your remote servers.
configure nginx to error logging at debug level.
Then perform the access with your private browser and then with your script using request_http and go through the generated log file and look for any difference.